# Rails 4 collection_check_boxes persistent after form refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, checked

I'm using Rails 4 **[collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)** in my forms. Filling out the form, I check some of the checkboxes. I've noticed that when the form refreshes after validation error, the checkboxes that were checked persists. Is this a feature of the tag? I couldn't find this information in the docs.

Checkbox form field code:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label "Area of Interest" %><br />
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :interest_ids, Interest.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
    <div class="collection-check-box">
      <%= b.check_box %>
      <%= b.label %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I do want the checkboxes to stay checked after form refresh but wanted to make sure it is a feature and not just a coincidence that is it working for me.

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a feature of the tag as long as you use `render :action` instead of `redirect_to :action` to render your form upon a failed save/validation:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.valid?
    redirect_to action: :show
  else
    render :new # @user gets passed to form_for
  end
end
```

The key distinction is that when you use `render :new`, the `@user` model instance from your create action is passed to  your form.

Now, in the new.html.erb view:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  # Fields using the syntax f.text_field :attr_name, `f.collection_check_boxes :attr_name`, etc will reference the :attr_name in both @user to populate the value(s). Also, @user.errors[:attr_name] to show an error message, if present.
end
```

Basically, what's happening is in your controller you're calling one of `save`, `create`, `validate`, or `valid?` on your model. A failed validation after calling one of these methods prevents a save to the database, but the failed values are still present in the `@user` object. Also, the `errors` object is now populated with information on which attributes failed to updated and the reason why the validation failed.

Thus, when you re-render your form, you see the check boxes are still selected because they're populated from the values in model instance itself. Similarly any fields with matching errors should show an error for that field as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the validation fail page refresh is the same action as a 'form refresh' unless you added language in your controller that would reset your form if the form fails to save.

When you check interest_ids the form and hit 'submit', it adds any checked value that passes validation into your model as a saved :interest_id value, so that saved value is what makes the checkboxes persist even if the whole form fails validation.

If you want to reset your form if any part of the form fails validation, I would suggest adding an if/else statement into your controller on the create action. @object.interest_ids = [] will reset the stored interest_ids on your object to an empty array, which will uncheck the boxes.

```html
def create
  @object = Object.new
  if @object.save
    redirect_to object_path(@object)
  else
    @object.interest_ids = []
    render :new
  end
end
```